# Best approach for Doctrine2 with productdata sharded per category

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine2 in a Symfony2 project and I've to build against an already existing MySQL database with productdata. There are about 40 productcategories and millions of products. Each category has it's own table in MySQL, all with the same schema.

Simplified:

[image: simplified schema]

Every table also has its own primary key ID field, so it's possible to have several products with the same ID, but coming from a different category.

All references to these products are now by category ID + product ID. The current software selects the data from the correct table based based on a defined mapping between the category ID and the MySQL table. This mapping is made in a seperate categories MySQL table, and rarely changes.

I've looked at [inheritance mapping in Doctrine2](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)  and it seems the best solution would be to make a mapped superclass. After that I can make 40 subclasses that extend this superclass, for each category one. I would still need some kind of mapping between the category ID and the correct subclass entity.

[image: inheritance mapping solution]

Is there a better approach to this? Because with this solution I would have to find the correct subclass entity based on the category ID.

Comment: Maybe we are missing infos but it just seems to me that the DB is badly build to start with. Do you really need 40 productcategories tables if they are all the same ?

Comment: Yes, the database schema is far from perfect but since a lot of other applications work on this years old database I can't just change it. The performance is the reason for splitting per category as the database needs to handle lots of queries per second, including inserts, updates and deletes.